# Redirect the request to a different url

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, ui-automation

Need to redirect remote url request to a localhost url. I don't have control on how this request will be called as its being called from webapp. Tried different tools such as Wiremock, mockserver, Traefik but nothing seems to work. These tools works as forward proxy but my scenario needs reverse proxy.

**Scenario**

> remote url (http://remoteurl)  --> local url (http://localhost:8080)

Some background: 
The webapp along with test script is deployed via docker.There is separate containers for webapp and test script. The internal network is working perfectly and script can run inside the docker environment.There are same ports open for some containers and thats why we are using domain name to communicate within the docker environment. My requirement is to run in local machine to debug the script and fix some issues as i get a hold on headless browsing session on docker.

Comment: can you provide more details? where is `docker` used in your scenario? How are you deploying the reverse proxy and the webapp?

Comment: @yzt see if the detail helps

Comment: if I understood you correctly, you want: host (run test script)  > docker (reverse proxy) > docker (webapp) ?

Comment: @yzT yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

Add a new container to your docker network, a `nginx`, exposing port 8888.

This nginx should have this config:

```
server {
    server_name proxy;
    listen 8888;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://webapp:8080;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

Now you can attack from your test script to `http://localhost:8888` and it will forward the traffic to the webapp.

This is assuming you can't just expose the webapp port to the localhost. If you can expose it, you just need to attack `http://localhost:8080` and forget about the reverse proxy.